# Is there a way to add a 'cool down' delay or require user input before repeating a transition,?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

With CSS there is an unexpected result when coding for an image or box to move when hovered over. If the mouse is in a position that is in the click area at the start of the transition but not at the end, the transition effect will repeat indefinitely and stutter if there is no delay. Below is a quick html / css demo of the issue:

```css
div {

  height:   200px;
  width:   200px;
  background-color: red;

}

div:hover {

  margin-left:  100px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html> <html> 

<head> <title> Hover / Transition Demo </title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></head> 

<body>

<div> </div>

</body> 

</html>
```

To reproduce the problem, hover your mouse over the left-hand side of the red box, this should cause the square to rapidly move left and right.

Is there a clean way around this eyesore? There are several solutions that can happen: The box stays in the start position; or the end position; there is a delay that applies only in this situation to avoid the stuttering effect; or the mouse is required to move at least one pixel before the transition repeats. Ideally I'd like all these solutions, but just one would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually try to make sure any animations that use transforms don't change the location or size of the hover trigger.  This would involve more markup to accomplish, but basically you would create a wrapper that maintains its position and captures the mouse event.  The animation then becomes strictly visual rather than functional in changing the position of the element.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution, but this demonstrates what I was trying to convey in my comment.  The hover state is on a parent of the red box.  The fact that you can drag your cursor over the red box shows that hovering over the red box is still triggering the hover effect.  This is because the negative margin is increasing the width of `.wrapper`, but this is the basic concept.  If you need a more detailed solution, you'll have to provide more information on the specific case you are working on rather than this simple demo.

**Edit:** I've updated the  code to use `pointer-events:none`.  It's [better supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) than I thought it was (IE 11+). This is a CSS rule that tells the browser to ignore mouse events (:hover in this case) originating from the element with the style rule.

```css
.wrapper {
  height:   200px;
  width:   200px;
}

.box {

  height:   200px;
  width:   200px;
  background-color: red;
  pointer-events: none;

}

.wrapper:hover .box {

  margin-left:  100px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html> <html> 

<head> <title> Hover / Transition Demo </title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></head> 

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box"> </div>
</div>

</body> 

</html>
```